# Problems with time

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I coded this snippet to log the users IP and time on my website. It works but something is wrong with the time:

```
public static void UserLogin(string iPaddress, string uname)
{
    DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now);
    string cet= dt.AddHours(1).ToString("F", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    .....

}
```

The website is on a server somewhere in UK and to adjust the login time to CET without going too sophisticated, I simply toughth adding the hours difference using (AddHours) but for some reason, and I do not understand why, whatsoever number I put in there "AddHours(1)" will never get added and moreover, right now that is 13:55 at my location in Italy, the time recorder by the method is 1:55 am that is 12 hours behind even if there is no hours added "AddHours(0)".
Some help to understand what is going on in this method will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert time between time zones in more controlled way, for example:

```
DateTime nowutc = DateTime.UtcNow;
var cet = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
var nowcet = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowutc, cet);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Obviously your code is working but still I do not understand what is wrong in mine.

Comment: Hi, I changed my code and I am using the snippet you gave me but I am still having problems. Locally on my machine it is fine but on the hosting server the code is returning 4 hours differences. It is now 16:32 CET, that means that at the server location (UK) is 15:32, the snippet is returning 07:32 pm? Any advice?